# Laravel Display data in views in Web Server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, entity-relationship

It gives me an error of "Trying to get property of non-object" can you help me? It works normally on my offline server but if I upload it on my liveserver it gives an error

I if I dd my controller gives result.

```
Collection {#287 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => Branch {#297 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:6 [▶]
      #original: array:6 [▶]
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #events: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "cashier" => User {#301 ▼
          #fillable: array:4 [▶]
          #hidden: array:2 [▶]
          #connection: "mysql"
          #table: null
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #attributes: array:8 [▼
            "id" => 5
            "name" => "qqqaMiracle Auer"
            "email" => "qqqapdickens@hotmail.com"
            "password" => "$2y$10$FArFw2M.dQBcsP4XAQ8a5.vYsfZHLp8S/6.1ZSaVGHaxuSKiYogbe"
            "usertype" => "cashier"
            "remember_token" => null
            "created_at" => "2018-01-22 03:30:20"
            "updated_at" => "2018-01-22 05:56:19"
          ]
          #original: array:8 [▶]
          #casts: []
          #dates: []
          #dateFormat: null
          #appends: []
          #events: []
          #observables: []
          #relations: []
          #touches: []
          +timestamps: true
          #visible: []
          #guarded: array:1 [▶]
          #rememberTokenName: "remember_token"
        }
      ]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
    1 => Branch {#298 ▶}
    2 => Branch {#299 ▶}
  ]
}
```

But when I make my code to disyplay the name of the cashier. with this code

```
@foreach($dataBranch as $Branch)
<tr class="item{{$Branch->id}}">
<td> <a class="name">{{$Branch->branch_name}}</a> </td>
<td> <a class="name">{{$Branch->cashier->name}}</a> </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

It gives me an error of "Trying to get property of non-object" can you help me? It works normally on my offline server but if I upload it on my liveserver it gives an error

Please help

Answer (score 0):

First you need to debug data in foreach and then try to use is_object() php function in condition to get the right data field.

You can verify you data in this way:

```
<?php 
//verify your data
foreach($dataBranch as $Branch) {

var_dump($Branch);

if(is_object($Branch)) {
  if(!empty($Branch->id)) {
   echo '$Branch->id';
  }
}}
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is accurate, as it says you are trying to access a property(`name`) of non-object(`$Branch->cashier`).

The most probable cause is one of the branches may not have a cashier, So you have to check `$Branch->cashier` exists before accessing the property from it.

```
{{ $Branch->cashier ?? $Branch->cashier->name : '' }}
```